# DLL load failed error when running mitmweb.exe

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I have `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.` error when running `mitmweb.exe`.
My steps:

- downloaded Windows installer from https://mitmproxy.org/ (v 5.0.1)
- installed (with defualt settings) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- ran `C:\Program Files (x86)\mitmproxy\bin\mitmweb.exe`

Full error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mitmweb", line 2, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\tools\main.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\tools\_main.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\master.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\addonmanager.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\eventsequence.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\http.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\net\http\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\net\http\request.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\net\http\message.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "mitmproxy\net\http\encoding.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "d:\a\mitmproxy\mitmproxy\.tox\cibuild\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\brotli.py", line 8, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[964] Failed to execute script mitmweb`

So what DLLs am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the only workaround I know is to **use version 4.0.4**.

Source(s):

- https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3804
- https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/3823